# Can anyone explain netty ChannelHandlerContext flush()?

Tags: java, netty, flush

Could someone explain what exactly `netty` method `ChannelHandlerContext flush()` does? Will it immediately send all messages through the network stopping any defined processing effectively bypassing any handlers in the pipeline?

Comment: Please research before asking question on StackOverflow (read [ask]), thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The [Netty in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action) book has a clearer definition:

**`write`:**

Writes a message to the Channel . This will call `write(ChannelandlerContext, Object msg, ChannelPromise)` on the next `ChannelOutboundHandler` in the `ChannelPipeline` .

Note: this does not write the message to the underlying Socket , but only
queues it. To write it to the Socket , call `flush()` or `writeAndFlush()` .

**`flush`:**

Flushes all pending writes of the Channel . This will call `flush(ChannelHandlerContext`) on the next `ChannelOutboundHandler` in the `ChannelPipeline`

Answer (score 2):

From Netty 4.1 documentation:

```
flush()
```

> Request to flush all pending messages via this ChannelOutboundInvoker.

- [ChannelHandlerContext Netty Documentation](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html)

You can find more examples here: [Code Examples for 
 ChannelHandlerContext.flush()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext&method=flush)

Comment: Yes,  I read this but it doesn't explain much. What does flush mean? Will the message be processed by the next handler or not?

Comment: J.Doe, I think the answer by @Riyafa solve your question.